# Solving Definite Integrals

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

Please, I am trying to solve definite integral and its work but the results not simplified.

```
F = Integrate[(x^4*Exp[x])/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, 44}]
```

This is the result

```
(1/(15 (-1 + E^44)))4 (-\[Pi]^4 + 
   E^44 (\[Pi]^4 + 
      30 (-1874048 + 42592 Log[-1 + E^44] - 2904 PolyLog[2, 1/E^44] - 
         132 PolyLog[3, 1/E^44] - 3 PolyLog[4, 1/E^44])) + 
   30 (-42592 Log[-1 + E^44] + 
      3 (468512 + 968 PolyLog[2, 1/E^44] + 44 PolyLog[3, 1/E^44] + 
         PolyLog[4, 1/E^44])))
```

Comment: in case you didn't know, the infinite integral has a nice simple form: `Integrate[(x^4*Exp[x])/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, Infinity}] (*4 Pi^4/15 *)`.  If you care about the difference between limits of `44` and `Infinity` you probably need to go to extended precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the result to a numerical value.

```
F = Integrate[(x^4*Exp[x])/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, 44}];
N[F]
```

> 25.9758

Visualisation

```
Show[Plot[(x^4*Exp[x])/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, -4, 48}],
 Plot[(x^4*Exp[x])/(Exp[x] - 1)^2, {x, 0, 44},
  Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: `NIntegrate` is dramatically faster, if you just need the numeric value.